# Paging for post history

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, revisions-list

Here's a suggestion.

We can see the editing history by clicking on the "edited: " link.

How about adding a left and right button in that location that simply pages through the edits while staying on the same page.

The reason being that you could stay on the question page without having to go back and forth.

Sometimes I find myself just wanting to see the previous version of an answer due to comments that were left which no longer make any sense.